# Info.plist does not change fields in Targets/MyApp/Info

Tags: swift, xcode, ionic-framework

i'am having a strange problem. When i modify the Info.plist for example if i add a new field i can see it, but when i go to App/Targets(MyApp)/Info i son't see any changes. Plus i'am localizing my app with different languages (English, German, Italian) so i have a localized version of Info.plist with the Base and other languages too. In build settings the Info.plist is linked correctly to App/Info.plist where the file is, plus i don't know if it could be useful but i made the project with Ionic capacitor 3.

So if i want to see a change for example the app name, i have to modify the info in App/Targets while if i modify the Info.plist in App folder nothing changes.

Comment: You will need to delete your iOS / Android folders and add them again via Capacitor for changes to take place.

Comment: Were you finally able to fix this? I am having the same problem